Docker, ip6tables and "Tags" for ip6tables
I'm starting to develop a tech-stack that generates some containers, identified by a common "container tag". I have a script to create the stack andone to destroy it.
As of late, i need to work with ip6tables.
I can happily allow anything needed in the create script but my problem is, that i cannot delete the rules as they have no dependency whatsoever.
Is it possible to somehow ass a "tag" to the allowed rules so that i can match on that and selectively destroy all entries with a specific "tag"?


Is it possible to somehow ass a "tag" to the allowed rules so that i can match on that and selectively destroy all entries with a specific "tag"?

Put all your netfilter rules into your own custom chains. E.g., if you're adding INPUT rules, do something like:
# Create "myproject-input" chain
iptables -N myproject-input

# Add a rule to INPUT chain to jump to "myproject-input" chain
iptables -A INPUT -j myproject-input

# Add a rule to the "myproject-input" chain
iptables -A myproject-input -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP

If you want to destroy all your entries, just flush the chain:
iptables -F myproject-input

You'll see that tools like Docker something very much like this. Take a look at the output of iptables-save and look at the chains that Docker creates; you'll note that the only rules it adds to the default chains are jump (-j) rules that redirect processing to one of the DOCKER* chains.
